# How to distinguish between route name if they have same route names

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

I created four resource-full controllers in same location and when I checked route list all four controller have same route name. How can I distinguish route name when I call them.
Below are my routes

```
Route::resource('lead/tutor', 'Admin\Tutor\TutorLeadController', ['as'=>'admin']);
Route::resource('screen/tutor', 'Admin\Tutor\TutorScreenController', ['as'=>'admin']);
Route::resource('shortlist/tutor', 'Admin\Tutor\TutorShortListController', ['as'=>'admin']);
Route::resource('approve/tutor', 'Admin\Tutor\TutorApproveController', ['as'=>'admin']);
```

Comment: what do you mean by same route name?

Comment: admin.tutor.index
admin.tutor.store
admin.tutor.create
admin.tutor.update
admin.tutor.destroy
amin.tuor.edit
All four routes have same name.

Comment: you should give different name `as=>admin.lead` ,`as => admin.tutor` etc

Comment: Thanks buddy. I was confused by this. Got it now

Comment: You need to use named routes. See the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give every route name,  different name `as=>admin.lead` ,`as => admin.tutor` etc.

It's called named route check it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing)

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why at first run it showed me correct route name, after changes to above solution it worked fine. But then i changed route name back to original it generated route name correctly.

```
    Route::resource('tutor/lead', 'Admin\Tutor\TutorLeadController', ['as'=>'admin']);
    Route::resource('tutor/screen', 'Admin\Tutor\TutorScreenController', ['as'=>'admin']);
    Route::resource('tutor/shortlist', 'Admin\Tutor\TutorShortListController', ['as'=>'admin']);
    Route::resource('tutor/approve', 'Admin\Tutor\TutorApproveController', ['as'=>'admin']);
```

And it generate route names as below

```
admin.lead.index
admin.lead.create
...
admin.lead.destroy
```

and also for other routes

```
admin.approve.index
....
admin.shortlist.index
....
admin.screen.index
.........   .create
ect
```